# Efficient packet decoding

Tags: java, network-programming, protocols, netty, snmp

I am working on a Netty application for the SNMP protocol. The protocol has 3 different versions `1,2,3` and a corresponding message format to go with those versions. I am wondering what is the most efficient way to decode these based on the variations between packet formats.

Snmpv1 message format: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion1SNMPv1MessageFormat.htm

Snmpv2 message format: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion2SNMPv2MessageFormats-2.htm

As you can see the messages differ in format. I would post v3 which differs by a lot but I can't post more than 2 links.

My initial idea was to make a reflection based decocder but it's proving to be rather troublesome.

Something along the lines of this (taken from a source on github):

```
    public <T> T decode(W buf, Class<T> clazz) throws Asn1Exception {
    if (typeEncoders.containsKey(clazz)) {
        return clazz.cast(typeEncoders.get(clazz).decode(buf));
    }

    T obj;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> sequence = (Map<String, Object>)annotatedTypeEncoders.get(UniversalType.SEQUENCE).decode(buf);
    try {
        obj = clazz.newInstance();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : sequence.entrySet()) {
            entry.getKey();
            Field field = clazz.getField(entry.getKey());
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(obj, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Asn1Exception("Unable to set fields on object", e);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

With a mapped class of something like this (my source):

```
public final class DefaultSnmpPdu implements SnmpCommonPdu {
@Asn1Type(type = Asn1Tag.INTEGER)
private SnmpMessageType type;
@Asn1Type(type = Asn1Tag.INTEGER)
private int requestId;
@Asn1Type(type = Asn1Tag.INTEGER)
private SnmpErrorType errorType;
@Asn1Type(type = Asn1Tag.INTEGER)
private int errorIndex;
@Asn1Type(type = Asn1Tag.SEQUENCE)
private Map<String, Object> variableBindings;

@Override
public SnmpMessageType getType() {
    return type;
}

@Override
public int getRequestId() {
    return requestId;
}

@Override
public SnmpErrorType getErrorType() {
    return errorType;
}

@Override
public int getErrorIndex() {
    return errorIndex;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getVariableBindings() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(variableBindings);
}
}
```

I am open to all ideas, thank you.

Comment: Err, why? SNMP4J is already written. Efficiency of decoding isn't a major concern when the rate-determining step is the network.

Comment: I dont want to use an already built library, this is for educational purposes.